# How can I format email that are sent by UIB

Tags: unificationengine

How can I format emails that are sent by UIB ? For example changing fonts, using different color and adding attachments.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting contents, user can send html mail by giving "contentType" as "text/html".

Please check the following api command for sending email with attachment

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send   --data "{ \"message\": { \"receivers\": [{\"name\": \"TO_NAME \", \"address\": \"TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS\" , \"Connector\": \"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER\", \"type\": \"to\"}],\"subject\":\"MESSAGE_SUBJECT\",\"parts\": [{\"id\": \"1\", \"contentType\": \"text/html\", \"data\":\"MESSAGE_HTML_CONTENT\" ,\"size\": MESSAGE_CONTENT_SIZE,\"type\": \"body\",\"sort\":0},{\"id\": \"1\", \"contentType\": \"IMAGE_TYPE\" , \"size\": IMAGE_SIZE, \"type\": \"image\", \"name\":\"IMAGE_NAME\",\"data\":\"BASE64_IMAGE",\"sort\":1}]}}" -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET -k